# Organizing a list based on another list

Tags: java, arrays

I have generated two lists of random numbers between 0 and 1, one using Math.random() and the other using simplex noise, and I am trying to sort the random list so it has peaks and troughs in the same places as the simplex noise list.

This is what I have so far;

```
public float[] organize(float[] list) {
    float[] organizedList = new float[list.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < simplexList.length; i++) {
        float smallestDifference = 2;

        for (int j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            float difference = list[j] - simplexList[i];

            if (difference < smallestDifference) {
                smallestDifference = difference;

                organizedList[i] = list[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return organizedList;
}
```

This method is supposed to find the item in the random array that is closest to the one in the simplex array and add that to the organized list. I was wondering if this is a good way to do it or if there is a better solution?

Comment: You could sort the array containing the data generated using `Math.random()` and binary search it for the closest matching number, which would reduce the computational complexity of your algorithm from O(n^2) to O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Are you sure it's not `Math.abs(list[j] - simplexList[i])`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Kth-largest item in the random list to substitute for the Kth-largest item in the simplex list.  That should guarantee that the shape of the result will match the shape of the original, at least as far as the placement of peaks and troughs goes.

To do that, I'd:

- sort the simplex list, while keeping track of the original index of each item in that list
- sort the random list
- build a result list by taking each item in turn from the sorted random list and placing it in the result list at the original index of the corresponding item in the sorted simplex list

The only tricky part is building the list that contains the original indexes of the sorted simplex values.  One straightforward way to do it would be to build an augmented list with each item containing the original simplex value and its index, and then sort that list on the simplex value.

An alternative, slightly neater way to do it is to start with a list that contains indexes in ascending order [ 0, 1, 2, 3, ... ] and then java.util.Collections.sort that list by applying a java.util.Comparator whose compare() method compared the appropriate values from the original simplex_list.  That would look like:

```
public in compare(Integer indexA, Integer indexB) {
    return simplex_list.get(indexA).compareTo(simplex_list.get(indexB));
}
```

For example, using the "simplex value augmented with index" approach:

```
simplex_list = [ 8, 10, 3, 2, 6, 20 ]

# Pair each simplex value with its index
augmented_simplex_list = [ 8@0, 10@1, 3@2, 2@3, 6@4, 20@5 ]

# Sort the value@index items according to value
sorted_augmented_simplex_list = [ 2@3, 3@2, 6@4, 8@0, 10@1, 20@5 ]

# Discard the value part of each item, leaving only the original 
# list index
#
sorted_simplex_index_list = [ 3, 2, 4, 0, 1, 5 ]

# Sort the random list
random_list = [ 5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 4 ]
sorted_random_list = [ 1, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9 ]

# Take each item of sorted_random_list and place it at the index 
# in the result list indicated by the corresponding item in
# the sorted_simplex_index_list.  That is, 
# sorted_random_list[0] goes to result_list[sorted_simplex_index_list[0]],
# sorted_random_list[1] goes to result_list[sorted_simplex_index_list[1]],
# and so on, giving:
#
result_list = [ 7, 8, 4, 1, 5, 9 ]
```

which has the shape of the original simplex list.

Of course if you go with the augmented simplex list approach you probably wouldn't really build an explicit sorted_simple_index_list, you'd just take the index part of the item from sorted_augmented_simplex_list.